# vimrc: how to auto change window focus when vim is loaded

Tags: vim, window, focus

I've let tagbar and NERDtree autoload when vim is opening any file. 
   The window layout from left to right is:

> NERDTree----My source code----TagBar

The problem is, each time vim is up, the NERDtree on the left gets the focus(keyboard). I wish to make the middle window(My source code) having the focus, so I can start coding immediately. Or else I have to C-w l to switch windows each time.

How to set this in ~/.vimrc?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugins probably use `:autocmd VimEnter` to open their sidebars. You can define a similar autocmd, but it has to run *after* the plugins'.

Put the following into `~/.vim/after/plugin/middleWindow.vim`:

```
autocmd VimEnter * 2wincmd w
```

This goes to the second available window.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky, because I don't know when in your start-up sequence, all three buffers are loaded. If you use Vim8, you can do the wincmd on a timer. This works for me:

```
call timer_start(100, { -> execute( "wincmd l") })
```